# Why the icon from 'native-base' is not shown up

Tags: react-native

I'm developing iOS application with React Native and using `Icon` from `native-base` in the navigation bar.

However, some icons are not shown up as the icon I expected there.

This is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import { Icon } from 'native-base';

export default class HomeTab extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
      <Icon name='md-add-circle-outline' style={{color: tintColor}} />
    )
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          HomeTab
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

This code is supposed to show up the icon below.
https://gyazo.com/b9a19f8de26261cb62e834cd7a0ca867

But, in fact, the icon below is shown up.
https://gyazo.com/5476d5b168f51014038470d85381c9e9

This is, I think, the [icon reference site](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/).

And this is my `package.json`.

```
{
  "name": "Sample",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.59.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.4.4",
    "babel-jest": "24.8.0",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.54.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Icon component also specify type component, most of the time it works but sometimes it gives error.

type is the name of the font, eg: 'AntDesign', 'MaterialCommunityIcons', etc

you can search for almost all icons [here](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/)